# nice scroll jquery plugin , something wrong in the full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using nice scroll plugin , It works well

But I have two problems with it,

**First problem:**  It doesn't take the full width of the scroll bar even if I increased the "cursor width" .. I will get the same problem.

**second problem:** when I use 'nice scroll'  I get a bottom scroll bar

How could I remove it?

here's the image, it will explain my points

[image]

Comment: Could you share your code ??

Comment: which code do you need exactly ?

Comment: $("html").niceScroll({
             
             
             cursorcolor:"#f8b307",
             cursorborder:"none"
             
         });

Comment: HTML of your screen.

Comment: and Do check the  cursor width option in chrome as this could be a browser specific issue